# Collection View delete item in depending on its location

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have created a collection view that pulls from an array of images (8 right now, but user can add more). I originally was using a scrollview, but found it easier with a collection, and thanks to this great community, went to a collection view. I need to find the indexPath to delete an item at a given point. So here is some code I have so far, but I am new to this specifically. Here is some code I currently have.

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!


 func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return imageArray.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! UserFeedCollectionViewCell
    cell.myImage.image = UIImage(named: imageArray[indexPath.row])
    cell.myImage.layer.cornerRadius = 12.0
    cell.myImage.clipsToBounds = true
    return cell
}

//delete item at current item - 2

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row > 2 {


        myCollectionView.deleteItems(at: [])
    }
}
```

Hope this will help and feel free to ask in the comments if you have a question.

Edit: Paging is enabled, and it is horizontal scrolling, and each image takes up the whole cell.

Comment: Just to clarify, you don't want the item two items back in index order, but in the user selected order, correct? So, the user would tap an item, then another item, and then another, and you need the first item they tapped on deleted from both the collection and its location in storage? Something like that?

Comment: Yes, which ever item the user is currently on, if it is greater than 2, delete 2 items back. Hope this can clarify. Example: img1, img2, img3. User starts on image 1, scrolls to next photo, (horizontally) and next image shows up, img2, and then swipes again to img3 and img1 then deletes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about keeping an array of tapped on image indices?

Define a variable for the indexes at the top:

```
var selected = [IndexPath]()
```

Then implement `didSelectItemAt` as:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selected.append(indexPath)
    if selected.count > 2 {
        let ndx = selecte.count - 3
        let twoBack = selected[ndx]
        myCollectionView.deleteItems(at:[twoBack])
    }
}
```

The above would work fine for the first selection, but at that point, you would need to figure out how you handle the next selection - whether you wipe the `selected` array and start over, or need to keep track of further selections to handle the next input.

Depending on how you want to proceed, the `selected` array would either need to be wiped or to be modified to remove the item that was deleted.